# How to print a certain page of a PDF received from Hazel

Tags: pdf, applescript

is there a way to print a certain page from a PDF document, which was received from Hazel (www.noodlesoft.com) i.e. via AppleScript?

In my case I always want to print just the 1st page of a PDF document.

If yes, would someone be so kind and provide the code for this. I tried it with Automator, but you can not select the page which you want to print.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could script it using CUPS with something like this :

```
do shell script "lp -o page-ranges=1 ~/Desktop/printpdf.pdf"
```